# Old stop motion cartoon series about a group of kids solving some cases about monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I don't really remember, but this was a creepy cartoon series, similar to *Scooby Doo*.

Some kids were facing some monsters in their life, but unlike in *Scooby Doo*, the monsters were real, and I remember that some of those monsters were real people.

I think the art style was clay motion, and I remember that in one episode, a ghost was trapped in a school restroom. In another episode, two ghosts got bullied and trapped, and turned into a giant melted cheese.

It's not *Scream Street*. It has a similar art style, but some monsters are real people with costumes or old Photoshop.

I watched this, I think, in 2007/2008. It has the '80s/'90s stop motion style. I watched it in English, I think on Nickelodeon. I don't really remember

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this cartoon, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, which country and language did you watch this in? And do you recall which specific television channel you might've seen this on?

Comment: first of all thank you second i watch it i think in 2007/2008 third it has the 80s/90s stop motion style so and i watch it in English i think in nickelodeon i don't really remember

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've added those details to your question. You also used the word "episode" in your description, so was this a series, rather than a one-off?

Comment: yes it is but i don't really remember how much episodes

Comment: The time frame does not match as it's more recent than what you remember, but could it be [_"Scream Street"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scream_Street_(TV_series))?

Comment: unfortunately it's not Scream Street the cartoon i talk about it have similar art style but some monsters are real people with costumes or old Photoshop

Comment: See if anything rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StopMotion

Comment: Like claymation? Action figures? Paper dolls?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/PhantomInvestigators or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_in_the_Night_(TV_series)?

Comment: will thank you so much it's  Phantom Investigators my memory are so bad that i didn't remember that it was claymotion not stop motion

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to a comment from @FuzzyBoots, I was able to find it: it's called [Phantom Investigator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_Investigators).

From Wikipedia:

> It was created using a special mixture of stop-motion (used for the main cast and the other citizens), puppetry (used for many of the supernatural creatures that are encountered), and live-action (used mainly for ghosts).

[image: A picture from the aforementioned animated show, as an example of what it looked like]

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't have the bandwidth to write up a proper answer, but congrats! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark. As a self-answer, you have to wait 48 hours after asking before it will let it go through, but clicking early will tell you how much longer you have.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you might be thinking about [Martin Mystery (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Mystery) (Martin Mystère in French), which is a French animated show about 3 people who worked for an organization (called "The Center" apparently) to fight the occults, monsters and stuffs like that (which, as you said, are real stuffs, unlike Scooby-Doo).

The cast was composed of 3 main characters:

- Martin Mystery, the main protagonist. He has a sophisticated watch with which he can pull out gadgets that can help him in various situations (DNA scanner, weapons, etc.).
- Diana Lombard, Martin's step sister (who more often than not dislikes him for being immature, although she doesn't hate him).
- Java the Caveman; initially, he was locked in one of the cells for the monsters. But Martin freed him and he became a full time member of their organization.

Here's a poster with the title and the 3 main characters below:

[image: A poster of the Martin Mystery show, depicting the 3 main protagonists who seem to be scared of something; most likely supernatural, as they fight the occult. The character on the left is Java the Caveman, who is a tough looking man with black hair and wearing an orange shirt with short sleeves with blue pants. The character in the middle is Martin Mystery. He's a blond 16 years old teenager, dressed in an opened short sleeve shirt with a flame pattern on top of a white T-shirt and beige pants. His blond hair comes up like a spike. He wears a watch with gadgets to help him in his mission. The character on the right is Diana Lombard, Martin Mystery's step sister. She has long brown hair and is dressed with something purple and a blue jean.]

Comment: This wasn't stop motion though, so this might be wrong too.

Comment: unfortunately yea this isn't what im talking about

Comment: @R.Lgaster I guess I'll still leave the answer around, in case it might help someone who, like me, thought about this one upon reading your question